# Highcharts draggable points - prevent hidding tooltip

Tags: angular, highcharts, draggable

Hi guys is it somehow possible to prevent hiding tooltip during dragging point for coulmn chart? It is visible only if cursor is hovering over but during dragging, it is little bit off and tooltip hides. I want to tooltip be visible during draging all the time.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-n9ufm?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:486-513)

Comment: you have to disable toolitp when you drag or click your point like that :   tooltip: {
                  enabled: false
                }

Answer (score 0):

You can add the small plugin below, which wraps `refresh` tooltip's method and hide the tooltip if the point is dragging.

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function(proceed, points) {
        var chart = points.series && points.series.chart;

        if (chart && chart.dragDropData && chart.dragDropData.isDragging) {
            chart.tooltip.getLabel().hide();
            chart.tooltip.isHidden = true;
            return false;
        }
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x5bqugoL/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts